# Probability of repeated numbers from $15$ previously drawn in a pick $5$ from $39$ game.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

How do you calculate the probability in a pick $5$ from $1$ to $39$ lottery game ($575,757$ possible combinations), that the next drawing will contain no repeated numbers from the previous THREE drawings? One repeated number? Two repeated numbers? Three repeated numbers? Four repeated numbers? All Five?

Keep in mind that the three previous drawings will produce a number set that can be anywhere from $5$ to $15$ numbers, but of course far more likely to be closest to $15$. Also, every drawing comes from a pool of $1$ to $39$.  This conditional yet independent situation has me baffled.

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the chance of each possible number of numbers in the previous three draws.  You will have $15$ different numbers $\frac {34\cdot 33 \cdot 32 \dots 25}{(39\cdot 38 \cdot 37 \cdot 36 \cdot 35)^2}\approx 9.968\%$ of the time.  For $n$ excluded numbers, you chance is $\frac {(39-n)!\cdot 34!}{39!\cdot (34-n)!}$.  Multliply them together and then add.

Added: the chance that there are $13$ distinct numbers in the previous three draws comes from three parts:  $0,1,2$ duplicates in the second draw.  The chance of one duplicate in the second draw is $\frac {5\cdot 5 \cdot 34 \cdot 33 \cdot 32 \cdot 31}{39\cdot 38 \cdot 37 \cdot 36 \cdot 35}\approx 0.4027$, where the first $5$ is the number of positions of the match and the second is the number to match.  The chance of exactly one duplicate in the next draw is $\frac {5\cdot 9 \cdot 30 \cdot 29 \cdot 28 \cdot 27}{39\cdot 38 \cdot 37 \cdot 36 \cdot 35}\approx 0.2380$.  This way of getting $13$ is then a $9.58\%$ chance.  The others are figured similarly.

Based on your last comment, it sounds like you want to beat the lottery based on avoiding numbers that have come up recently.  To check this, it would be easier to separate the $3857$ draws into bins based on how many numbers had come up in the previous three weeks.  Then you can just use that as data and not calculate the chance of $15$ different numbers coming up.

Let's assume there are $13$ different numbers that came up in the last three draws.  The chance of not duplicating one this draw is $\frac {26\cdot 25 \cdot 24 \cdot 23 \cdot 22}{39\cdot 38 \cdot 37 \cdot 36 \cdot 35}\approx 11.425\%$  The chance of duplicating exactly one is $\frac {5\cdot 5 \cdot 26\cdot 25 \cdot 24\cdot 23}{39\cdot 38 \cdot 37 \cdot 36 \cdot 35}\approx 12.983\%$  You can check them against your data.

Comment: Ross, can you clarify your answer? I'm simply not getting it.

Comment: Do you see how I got the chance no number is repeated?  To have no repeats in two draws, the first number in the second draw will not match with chance $\frac {34}{39}$, the second will not match with chance $\frac {33}{38}$ and so on.  For the third draw we again have all $39$ numbers available for the first one.

Comment: Yes I do follow that part, and your answer of nearly 10% matches my collected data from over 3800 draws. Unfortunately I am not comprehending your answer past that.

Comment: So now, if there are $15$ different numbers in the three draws, the chance none of them will be seen in the next draw is $\frac {24\cdot 23\cdot 22\cdot 21\cdot 20}{39\cdot 38 \cdot 37 \cdot 36 \cdot 35}=\frac {(39-15)!34!}{39!(34-15)!}$  The factorials make it easier to express it for an unknown $n$

Comment: Ah. So how could I write the formula to get, for example, the probability of 4 numbers repeating from the past three draws, IF the past three draws already had 2 different repeated numbers within, actually creating a set of 13?

Comment: In retrospect, a better way to have phrased my initial question is: What is the probability that 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 numbers from the previous three drawings will repeat in the next drawing of a pick 5 from 39 lottery game?  There are six answers.

Comment: You will still need to start with the calculation of the probability that the previous three draws had $5,6,7,\dots 15$ distinct numbers represented.

Comment: If I follow you correctly, this is a two-part operation, the first part being your statement about calculating the prob. of 5-15 distinct numbers possible. Since I will already KNOW how many duplicates the previous three draws contain by looking at the recent draw history(and most often it's 0, 1 or 2 duplicates), can I calculate and then reference those numbers as 'constants' to use for the second operation? Which is calculating for the probability of 0-5 duplicates in the next draw? Is the 0-5 duplicates the "n" that you reference? What am I missing here?

Comment: I am only trying to verify my collected data is following the probabilities. The data states that from 3857 draws, after three draws, 0 repeats occurs 12%, 1 repeat = 32%, 2 repeats = 34%, 3 repeats = 18%, 4 repeats = 4%, and 5 repeats = .3%

Comment: Ross, I actually play combos that have 4 numbers from the previous 3 drawings. Trending. Although various 4 repeat situations appear on average twice a month (games draw 14 times per week), it does have the advantage of a much lower total number of combinations possible, should one of them hit at all!  I take it even a level further, tracking these 4-repeat situations individually by ALL the possible ways they could occur. So in that respect, I do have the bins set up that you mentioned.  Out of 3857 drawings, any type of 4repeat situation from the past three draws has occurred 140 times.

Comment: I also track all the various 0-5 repeats-after-three-drawing situations as well, which I gave the percentage totals for above. It is some interesting data. I just want to know if the data is even close to what the probabilities dictate they should be. BTW thank you for your expertise and patience!

Comment: "Let's assume there are 13 different numbers that came up in the last three draws. The chance of not duplicating one this draw is 26⋅25⋅24⋅23⋅2239⋅38⋅37⋅36⋅35≈11.425% The chance of duplicating exactly one is 5⋅5⋅26⋅25⋅24⋅2339⋅38⋅37⋅36⋅35≈12.983% You can check them against your data."   What changes in the second formula to calculate the probability of two, three four or five duplicates?